# Put $(a \leftrightarrow b) \wedge c$ in DNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$(a \leftrightarrow b) \wedge c$$

I'm having problems with this. If I do:
$$(a \rightarrow b) \wedge (b \rightarrow a) \wedge c$$
then
$$(\neg a \vee b) \wedge (\neg b \vee a) \wedge c$$
But now I'm stuck.
I can do this but it gets too complicated... I need the "ORs of AND terms where every AND term consists of all variables."

I can distribute the $c$, but then I get a conjunctive form.

$$[(\neg a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c)] \wedge [(\neg b \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge c)]$$

Am I making this too complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  Try starting with
$$a\leftrightarrow b\quad\equiv\quad (a\wedge b)\vee(\neg a\wedge \neg b)\ .$$

Comment: Thanks! How would I go from $(\neg a \vee b) \wedge (\neg b \vee a)$ .....to..... $(a \wedge b)\vee(\neg a \wedge \neg b)$?

Comment: You could use the distributive laws to obtain four terms, two of which are contradictions.  What I was actually thinking was more on "semantic" grounds:  $a\leftrightarrow b$ just means that $a$ and $b$ are both true, or both false.  However this may not be admissible, depending what kind of approach you are expected to use.

Comment: @Jonathan - how to go from $(\lnot a \lor b) \land(\lnot b \lor a)$ to $(a \land b) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b)$ ? You must distribute step-by-step. The LHS becomes : $[\lnot a \land (\lnot b \lor a)] \lor [b \land (\lnot b \lor a)]$ and in turn : $(\lnot a \land \lnot b) \lor (\lnot a \land a) \lor (b \land \lnot b) \lor (b \land a)$. But $\lnot a \land a$ is *False* and $p \lor F$ is equivalent to $p$, so that you can "cancel" $(\lnot a \land a)$ and $(b \land \lnot b)$ obtaining : $(\lnot a \land \lnot b) \lor (a \land b)$.

Answer (score 0):

David's hint is the best way to go, but I'll also mention that you are making the distribution harder than it needs to be.  You could just go from

$(\neg a \lor b) \land (\neg b \lor c) \land c$

to

$(\neg a \lor b) \land ( [\neg b \land c] \lor [a\land c])$

And from there you can distribute the remaining conjunction as a big long ugly thing, but it's a margin better than the distribution you would have to do in the next step of what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at a truth table for your expression

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&\left(A\Longleftrightarrow B\right)\wedge C\\
\hline 0&0&0 &0\\
0&0&1 &1\\
0&1&0 &0\\
0&1&1 &0\\
\hline 1&0&0 &0\\
1&0&1 &0\\
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&1\\
\end{array}

Your expression is true *if and only if*

- $A$ is false **and** $B$ is false **and** $C$ ist true **or**
- $A$ is true **and** $B$ is true **and** $C$ ist true

Thus your DNF is given by
$$\left(\lnot A\wedge \lnot B \wedge C\right) \vee\left(A\wedge B\wedge C\right) $$